# how to change sites contents Using Chrome Extension ? (Example)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I Need A Page Action Or Browse Action with Files That Change  An element In A Website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

You can add javascript scripts and css stylesheets to a page to change the content.

good luck!

an example to change the background of www.google.com:
you create a .css file with:

```
body{
  background-color:black;
  }
```

when you made the .css file, add this to manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
    "css": ["[name].css"]
  }
],
```

matches means it will be added to any website that begins with http://www.google.com/ because of the '*'.

Comment: Oh !1 Thank You Very Much !
It's Helpful ... I Wish taht i have 15 reputation to Vote  But Sorry

Comment: If your question is solved, you can click the checkmark ;)