# Add A java Script file to browser Using Google extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I  Add A java Script file to browser Using a Google extension

I Need To Add A CSS To Facebook Using JavaScript And CSS And necessary Files.

Comment: Duplicate of [change google layout automaticly with google extention , URGENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677583/change-google-layout-automaticly-with-google-extention-urgent) and [how to change sites contents Using Chrome Extension ? (Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666449/how-to-change-sites-contents-using-chrome-extension-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).
Content script allows insertion of JS and CSS files on web pages. Other objects can then be loaded using JS.

Comment: Can You Please Give Me Extension Example To Add A java Content to Google  (Any Java Script )

Comment: @MrFares Come on. The documentation is served on a plate, and you don't even bother reading it? What is the difference between this and the previous question by the way? Please do not duplicate questions.

Comment: @RobW I Am Very Sorry , I Didn't Knew That The Dublicated Question Is Forbidden .
Can I Restore The Ability Of Asking Question By Any Way ?
Please , Answer Me .

Comment: @MrFares I did not remove your ability to ask questions. You did it yourself. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) to see how you can restore the right to ask questions.

Comment: It's Ok . I Restored It , Thank You ! .... You Are Helping Me !